# Take a series of randomly generated int() and adding them together, when the number of int()s is not known beforhand. [PYTHON-3]

Tags: python-3.x

I'm stumped.  I can get the numbers from the text file and I can display them in python, but I cannot add the numbers in that file together unless I know beforehand HOW MANY numbers there are.  I tried asking my teacher, but he didn't understand my question.  I don't want the answer, I just want to know what I'm missing.

```
def main():
    infile = open('rand.txt', 'r')
    testline = infile.readline()
    print("The numbers are:")
    for line in open('rand.txt'):
        amount = int(line)


        print(amount)
        #part of the code that is supposed to take the numbers in amount and add them together.


main()
```

Output:

The numbers are: 
12
23
34
42

The numbers are randomly generated, I cannot determine how many numbers
there are or their value, only that they are integers.

Comment: Hint: if there are zero lines in the file, what's the answer? If there is one line in the file, how is the answer different?

Comment: Let's see. zero lines means the program crashes. I'll have to fix that with a try.  Aside from that, maybe |


while reading_the_line != '':
    variable? = line.readline()?
|
That brings up the question again how I can save these numbers if I don't know how many numbers there are.

Comment: Are the numbers all on 1 line in the input file, delimited by spaces? If so, **numbers = map(int,open('rand.txt').readline().split(' '))** Or are they each on their own line.  In that case, **numbers = [int(line) for line in open('rand.txt')]**.  Adding them together is simply **sum(numbers)**.  If there are some blank lines in your input file, then do something like **numbers = [int(line) for line in open('rand.txt') if line.strip()]**

Comment: numbers = (int(amount) for line in open('rand.txt'))
        numbers = int(numbers)
        sum(numbers)
        
        print(numbers)

line 10, in main
    numbers = int(numbers)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'generator'